# Syncdb error when creating CustomUser

Tags: django, django-models

The issue is that I create Custom User:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And in `settings.py` write this:`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.CustomUser'`
And when I run manage.py syncdb for the first time(when db doesn't contains any tables), it throws an error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist` 
But when I run `manage.py syncdb` when db with tables already exist, then it's okay, just create additional tables. What's wrong to run it when db doesn't contain tables?

Comment: What django version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1. Create a `migration` directory in the directory of the app containing your custom user model.
2. Create an empty `__init__.py` file inside the `migration` directory.
3. Execute `./manage.py makemigrations`.
4. Execute `./manage.py migrate`.

I think when you use a custom user model, you need to create migrations. Besides, `syncdb` is already deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9 so it's better to start using the `./manage.py migrate` command.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, Your CustomUser table has relation with auth_group table, so unless that table is created or exists, you cannot create this new table in db.

When you say 'db with tables already exist, then it's okay', did You create the tables manually or included admin app in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Because if u include admin app, it will automatically create the auth_group table, so you will not see that issue

Comment: Yes, I include admin app: 'django.contrib.admin', but the issue remains